# Why would posting a notification cause a crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit, nsnotificationcenter

I use the following code to post a notification, but it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
```

in my constants.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString *const PLAYER_ID;
extern NSString *const RANDOM_NUMBER;

extern NSString *const AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION;
extern NSString *const UNAUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION;

@interface RIYConstants : NSObject
{

}

@end
```

in my constants.m file

```
#import "RIYConstants.h"

NSString *const PLAYER_ID = @"playerId";
NSString *const RANDOM_NUMBER = @"randomNumber";

NSString *const AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION = @"AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION";
NSString *const UNAUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION = @"UNAUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION";

@implementation RIYConstants

@end
```

The method where it crashes is a handler that is called when game center authenticates:

```
-(void)authenticatedPlayer:(GKLocalPlayer*)localPlayer
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
     ......
}
```

I have no idea why it crashes. It does not crash every time the notification is posted (seems random).

EDIT:
There is only one object that registers to receive the notification. The init method, and the selector that is called are below. I don't think there is anything that should cause the crash. Both _label and _joinGame are SKLabelNodes

```
-(id)init
{ ...
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(addGameCenterOption) name:AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
...
}

-(void)addGameCenterOption
{
    _label.text = @"";
    _joinGame.text = @"Start multiplayer game";
    _signedIn = YES;
}
```

EDIT: I have changed the app, so that there are no objects registered to observe the notification, but it still crashes (randomly).

Comment: Did some other object, which has since been deallocated, register to receive this notification and not unregister before deallocation?

Comment: There is only one object that has registered to observe this event, and it never gets deallocated during the lifetime of the app.

Comment: What crash message did you get?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0xb14595d5

Comment: You're sure it's not crashing in your notification handler?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It crashes at the line where I post the notification, and it is not reproducible - happens randomly.

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely caused by a registered observer, which has been released at the time the notification is sent, but the observer didn't unregister.

Ensure that all classes that add the observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addGameCenterOption) name:AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
```

do also remove the observer before they are released:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self AUTHENTICATED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
```

Comment: There is only one object that is registered to listen, and it never gets released.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are modifying UI elements, add an assert at the start of addGameCenterOption to insure you are on the main thread. Also, do something indirect before interacting with the elements, like logging their class to verify that they still exist before setting any property.

If you set an exceptions breakpoint (left pane), Xcode should show the exact line causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused because the function signature for my selector was incorrect. I had specified a selector without a param: `#selector(MyClass.myFunc)`,

but the method was defined as follows:

```
class MyClass {
    ...

    @objc func myFunc(completion: (() -> ())?)
        // function body
    }
}
```

After realizing that this signature wasn't allowed for Selectors, I updated my code like this.

```
class MyClass {
    ...

    @objc func functionForMySelector() {
        myFunc(completion: nil)
    }

    func myFunc(completion: (() -> ())?)
        // function body
    }
}
```

and defined my selector like this: `#selector(MyClass.functionForMySelector)`